# Solving a recurrence relation with a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, recurrence-relations, recursion

In my attempt to derive an equation for the population of Minecraft cows in a farm given some number of 5 minute periods, n; I'll spare the game mechanics at play. I came up with the following recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = 1.5\int_0^{n-4} T(x) \, dx,\space\space\forall n \ge 4$$
$$T(n) = 2,\space\space0\le n\lt 4$$

Has a similar problem been observed before, with a potentially infinite depth recursive integral? I haven't seen it in any of my classes (Computer Science major). Google yielded nothing relevant, however I might be missing some crucial vocabulary here.

My best thoughts on solving it would be doing a guess and proving it with strong induction, as was my intention going into crafting this equation, but I'm curious if there is a better way. Any relevant knowledge, vocabulary, or pointers are appreciated.

Some work towards a guess:

Result bounds by problem definition:
$$1.5^{n/4}\le T(n)\le 1.5^n$$

which is to say (greedily):

$$1.1^n\le T(n)\le 1.5^n$$

as there is more than a 50% increase every 20 minutes (4 counts of 5 minutes), and less than a 50% increase every 5 minutes. Intuitively, the base is probably some irrational number between 1 and 1.5, potentially a non-constant base derived from n, with an exponent of n. I believe it is an error to think that 4x 50% increases is a 200% increase in this case, as the number of grown cows (i.e. T(n)) changes every 5 minutes, not every 20. As such, the exponent should be n.

I do imagine an exponential solution, as the growth is experimentally and intuitively, a delayed exponential growth. This imposed limit comes from examining if cows grew at a rate of 50% every 5 minutes for the best case as opposed to 50% every 20 minutes for the worst case. In reality, every 5 minutes, the amount of cows grown up changes due to maturation delay. Due to this delay, we cannot reach the ideal of a base of 1.5, but similarly, because we are not as inefficient to only breed the cows every 20 minutes instead of 5 minutes (the ideal), $\sqrt[4] 1.5$ = ~1.1 as a base is also not attained.

This intuitively confirms the likelihood of some irrational answer, but doesn't point me to any exact guesses, yet.

Comment: Are you sure this is the formula you want?  It's not continuous, or increasing, since $T(4)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that what I found is probably an extraneous solution, since substituting the solution back into the integral yields $c_2=0$ or $T_0=0$ (the trivial solution). As vadim123 pointed out in his comment to the OP, maybe there is something wrong with the equation.

---

It's a particular case of the [Volterra integral equation of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation). Let's write the problem as
$$
T(n) = a \int_0^{n-k}T(x)\ dx, \ \ \ T(k) = T_0.
$$
Differentiating both sides i.r.t. $n$ (the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) can be helpful) one has
$$
T'(n) = a T(n-k),
$$
which is a simple [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). Using $T=c_1 \exp (c_2 n)$ yields
$$
c_1 c_2 \exp (c_2 n) = a c_1 \exp(-c_2 k) \exp (c_2 n),
$$
showing that $c_2$ must satisfy the transcedental relation
$$
c_2 = a \exp(-c_2 k),
$$
leading to
$$
c_2= \frac{W(a k)}{k},
$$
in which $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). From the initial condition one has
$$
c_1 = T_0\exp(-c_2 k)
$$
and, therefore,
$$
T(n) = T_0 \exp \left( c_2 (n-k)\right), \ \ n\ge k.
$$

The following graph depicts the solution for the case with $a=1.5$, $k=4$ and $T_0 = 2$.
[image]

Comment: This is truly amazing, thank you for putting forth the effort here. An inspiring answer!

Comment: @JavaProphet You are welcome! But please, notice that there is something wrong somewhere, as vadim123 pointed out. If that's the case, the solution I presented cannot describe correctly your problem. Let me know if you change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compute $T(n)$ for integer $n \ge 4$, you may just compute a sum (you can think of it as applying the trapezoidal rule). I you make the current value $T(n)$ depend only on the previous 5 values of $T$ and keep the structure of your formula, you would get something like

$$
T_n = \frac 32 \times \frac{1}{2} \left(T_{n-5} + 2 T_{n-4}+2T_{n-3}+2 T_{n-2}+T_{n-1} \right)
$$

If you solve this difference equation you'll see that it has an exponential growth, slightly affected by oscillations of smaller magnitude (the characteristic polynomial has two pairs of complex roots).

Answer (score 0):

$$
t_n = \alpha\sum_{k=4}^{n-4}t_k\\
t_{n-1} = \alpha\sum_{k=4}^{n-5}t_k
$$

then

$$
t_n-t_{n-1} = \alpha t_{n-4}
$$

so considering $\{r_k, k=1,\cdots,4\}$ the roots of $\gamma^4-\gamma^3-\alpha = 0$ we have

$$
t_n = \sum_{k=1}^4C_k r_k^n
$$

with $\{C_k, k=1,\cdots,4\}$ constants depending on the boundary conditions.